# Can I use IDXGIFactory2::CreateSwapChainForHwnd for directx 11.0

Tags: c++, windows, directx-11

As I undrestood, IDXGIFactory2::CreateSwapChainForHwnd was added in DXGI 1.2 API so if the method D3D11CreateDevice will return pFeatureLevel equal D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0 we able to use only DXGI 1.1 API, therefore we should call IDXGIFactory::CreateSwapChain instead of IDXGIFactory2::CreateSwapChainForHwnd. Am I right?

```
    HRESULT D3D11CreateDevice(
  [in, optional]  IDXGIAdapter            *pAdapter,
                  D3D_DRIVER_TYPE         DriverType,
                  HMODULE                 Software,
                  UINT                    Flags,
  [in, optional]  const D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL *pFeatureLevels,
                  UINT                    FeatureLevels,
                  UINT                    SDKVersion,
  [out, optional] ID3D11Device            **ppDevice,
  [out, optional] D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL       *pFeatureLevel,
  [out, optional] ID3D11DeviceContext     **ppImmediateContex
```

Comment: To make it simple, DXGI version is not related to D3D feature level (in fact, some DXGI formats are limited depending on D3D level). You should be able to get an IDXGIFactory2 reference event when choosing D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0. Have you tried?

Comment: Thank  you for answer. Yes I am able to get IDXGIFactory2 reference. Actualy the issue is that user had crash when  IDXGIFactory2::CreateSwapChainForHwnd was called and I have assumption that the cause is the version of directx but I can't request this info from user)

Comment: When something is not supported, you don't get a crash, you get an error (HRESULT) value.

Comment: Does your customer's system have the DirectX 11.1 Runtime installed or later? If they are on Windows 8.0, Windows 8.1, Windows 10, or Windows 11 it will always be there. If they are using Windows 7, then it's only there if they have KB2670838 installed. Otherwise they have DirectX 11.0 and the DXGI 1.2 interfaces are *not* available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess here is that your customer is running Windows 7, and is missing the DirectX 11.1 Runtime which is installed by the [KB2670838 update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/platform-update-for-windows-7-sp1-and-windows-server-2008-r2-sp1-d97da9ca-c15c-b21f-ebb0-838f7be8d9f6).

See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3darticles/platform-update-for-windows-7), as well as [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/directx-11-1-and-windows-7/) and [this follow-up post](https://walbourn.github.io/directx-11-1-and-windows-7-update/).

It's probably best to just tell customers you require KB 2670838 if they are using Windows 7. Supporting the DirectX 11.0 Runtime is certainly possible, but there are a number of quirks and you have to use DXGI 1.1 interfaces for the swapchain. See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/anatomy-of-direct3d-11-create-device/).

KB 2670838 is also available from [Microsoft Download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36805) as MSU files if the customer has Internet access issues.

> You should recheck the error handling of your application. You should have gotten an error `HRESULT` when you tried to QueryInterface the `IDXGIFactory2` interface if the system only had DirectX 11.0 on it. Remember if a function returns `HRESULT`, it's not safe to ignore the return value: Use `FAILED` or `SUCCEEDED` or a fast-fail like [ThrowIfFailed](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ThrowIfFailed) to make sure you hit the failure when it happens and not sometime later.

These days it's best to require Windows 7 Service Pack 1 if you support Windows 7. For example, the last few releases of Visual C++ only support Windows 7 SP1. That said, KB2670838 is *not* included in the Service Pack 1 package. It's pushed out via Windows Update as a recommended update, but if you have WU turned off or have created a fresh install of even Windows 7 SP1, you can be missing it. Note that KB2670838 doesn't support Windows 7 RTM in any case.

> Don't use 'Direct3D Hardware Feature Level' to infer the supported DirectX APIs. It's best to just QueryInterface for the `ID3D11Device1` if you want to check after creating the `ID3D11Device` to see if DirectX 11.1 is present, but a more direct test is to try to QUeryInterface the `IDXGIFactory2` interface.